# Angular 9 - onSameUrlNavigation='reload' not triggering router event

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular9

My Angular 9 app has a CustomErrorHandler, and an ErrorPageComponent. When any exception is thrown throughout the app, the CustomErrorHandler will tell the router to navigate to ErrorPageComponent. However, there is a button inside ErrorPageComponent which *could* throw its own exception, in which case I want CustomErrorHandler to still tell the router to navigate to ErrorPageComponent, as is normal. However, when ErrorPageComponent is routed to itself in this way, it needs to call its initialization method a second time.

Normally, if you want a component to call an initialization method after routing to itself, you can simply subscribe to the routing event. Then, as long as you have correctly set onSameUrlNavigation to reload, when the component navigates to itself, the router will trigger a routing event will call whichever callback method your component has used to subscribe to it.

However, when my CustomErrorHandler tells the router to navigate to ErrorPageComponent, no routing event is triggered.

This will make more sense if you look at the code:

Here's my route config inside app-routing.module.ts:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'normal', component: NormalComponent},
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/normal', pathMatch: 'full'}
];

const volitileRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'error', component: ErrorPageComponent}
];

const fallbackRoute: Routes = [
  { path: '**', component: Error404PageComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    RouterModule.forRoot(volitileRoutes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'}), // I've correctly set onSameUrlNavigation
    RouterModule.forRoot(fallbackRoute)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here is the CustomErrorHandler which will redirect to the ErrorPageComponent:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {

  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone, private router: Router){
    super();
  }

  handleError(error: any){
    // error handling code here

    console.log('error caught'); // I've confirmed that my CustomErrorHandler is in fact handling errors.

    /* This is not the normal way to do navigation. But for reasons I don't understand, this
       is the only way to get navigation to work from within an ErrorHandler; you cannot simply
       call router.navigate like normal from within an ErrorHandler. */
    this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigate(['/error']));
  }
}
```

Finally, here is ErrorPageComponent:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-error-page',
  templateUrl: './error-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./error-page.component.css']
})
export class ErrorPageComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private navSubscription = new Subscription();

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.navSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe((e: any) => {
      console.log('route event triggered'); // this line is never reached
      if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        // do initialization code
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.navSubscription?.unsubscribe(); // this prevents a memory leak
  }
}
```

As I mentioned in my code comments, I've confirmed that CustomErrorHandler is correctly handling the error, and is calling the router navigation method. However, the subscription callback method passed to the router navigation event is never called. What am I doing wrong? How do I subscribe to routing events in ErrorPageComponent?

Comment: Could you create a StackBlitz demo ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried to first redirect to dummy location, and then redirect to your actual component,

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(()=>
     this.router.navigate(['/error'])
);
```

I suggest you to set the first location as a location with ngOnInit and ngOnDestroy that are not doing a lot of actions because this will wait the init and destroy before routing to the new location.

Doing this you don't need to use `onSameUrlNavigation`, I think it's way better because you don't need to use a subscription, and so destroy it, you don't have to  set `onSameUrlNavigation` and you can simply reload when you want with a simple function.

But if you want to use your subscription, move it in your constructor instead of in your `ngOnInit` function.

Comment: Hey thanks! This does exactly what I need. Although it's kinda strange that achieving something so simple in Angular requires two redirects like this...

Comment: Yes, I am agree with you, but on one hand onSameUrlNavigation is not really user friendly to understand and setting up but don't need two redirects, and on the other hand we have this option which is really easy to understand and use, but that is not the standard way :/ So I think for both methods it's strange to implement this simple action in Angular ^^

Comment: For sure. It's weird that there is no easy means to do this in Angular.

Do you know why my onSameUrlNavigation solution didn't work? Do you think it's a bug?

Comment: The only thing I see could be your subscription, have you tried to put it on your constructor instead of your ngOnInit method ? I had the same need, a 'child' in a 'parent' component, and implementing the onSameUrlNavigation never worked so I tried something else, and so I am not able to help you a lot with this concept :/

Comment: nah that's fine, your solution was a big help. thanks!

Comment: Thanks Alexis. I've also gived a try to onSameUrlNavigation , without any luck. The documentation specifies that you only need to configure the router with this param set to 'reload' and then just navigate to same route... maybe I don't get it, I do hope for a best practice answer though :)